# How to open mat-menu on a dynamic nested menu with hover?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a nested menu with dynamic inputs from json.

I have the stackblitz of my dynamic nested menu. I want to make this on hover.
https://dynamic-nested-menus-w6t17z.stackblitz.io

This stackblitz has on hover but the template is not recursive.(like the above project) 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-nested-menu-yclrmd?embed=1&file=app/nested-menu-example.html

Any help in making this both features in single app .
thanks.